# TELEBOT Как сделать рассылку определенному пользователю?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, telebot

Прошу помощи. Начал заниматься разработкой телеграмм ботов недавно и в базах данных не очень шарю. Хочу сделать рассылку в боте не всем пользователям а определенному пользователю написать сообщение. Как это можно реализовать? Спасибо!

Comment: а где связь между "отправить сообщение определенному пользователю" и "база данных"?

Comment: идет сохранение user_id пользователя в бд и в нужный момент "вытаскивается" и на этот id отправляется сообщение. только манипуляции с бд я не знаю как сделать

Comment: Как вы хотите вызывать рассылку? По расписанию, по команде, отложено?

Comment: по команде лучше)